# X11 Problems when using CImg header in XCode on Mac OSX 10.11.6

Tags: xcode, macos, x11, cimg

I added X11 to my header search paths, library search paths, and I linked the binary to the X11 library in the build settings and build phases in XCode however I am still getting the errors shown in the picture below. I am 99.999% Sure the problem is X11 because when I disable the display capabilities the warnings aren't there. Any ideas on what I can do next?

[image]
[image: xcode settings1]

[image: xcode setting2]

[image: xcode settings3]

[image: xcode settings4]

[image: errors in XCode]

Comment: How exactly did you add X11 to your library search path? This is a linker error, so most likely the linker just can't find your X11 libraries.

Comment: Went to the Build Settings and added /opt/X11/include/ X11, /opt/X11/lib, /opt/X11/include in my header and library search paths and I went to the build phases and added X11 under "Link Binary with Libraries"

Comment: Also the some of the paths included in the CImg file were incorrect. Like the XLib.h file path being X11/include/X11/XLib.h instead of just X11/XLib.h. I fixed all of that but I still get the same errors I posted here.

Comment: Please show a screen grab of your linker settings.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Just edited. I'm also getting different errors now within the locale.h file. Will post those too.

Comment: I presume you have installed **XQuartz**?

Comment: yep. I am able to compile the program with clang in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your build settings a little incorrect. Here is a very simple program to get you started - you can choose to display PNG, TIFF or JPEG files by using `libpng`, `libtiff` or `libjpeg` which I am assuming you have installed using **homebrew** with:

```
brew install libpng libjpeg libtiff
```

Here is the code:

```
#define cimg_display  1
#define cimg_use_png  1
#define cimg_use_tiff 1
#define cimg_use_jpeg 1

#include "CImg.h"
using namespace cimg_library;

int main() {
    // Load image
    CImg<unsigned char> image("/Users/mark/Desktop/test.tif");
    
    // CImg<unsigned char> image("/Users/mark/Desktop/test.png");
    // CImg<unsigned char> image("/Users/mark/Desktop/test.jpg");
    // CImg<unsigned char> image("/Users/mark/Desktop/test.pnm");

    image.display();
}
```

The only build settings needed are as follows:

[image]

and

[image]

The `/Users/mark/src/CImg` one is for the `CImg.h` header file I manage with `git`, keeping it in sync with the `CImg` distribution on GitHub.

Note the following:

- CImg can read NetPBM (PGM/PBM/PPM and actually PFM) images without any extra code or libraries or dependencies
- CImg can read TIFF, PNG, JPEG without needing ImageMagick if you `#define cimg_use_tiff` or `#define cimg_use_png` or `#define cimg_use_jpeg` as long as you set the include path the library path and the library names as I have shown above.
- CImg can read anything that **ImageMagick** can read if you install that package.

Comment: Yay! That got rid of the locale errors! Now XCode can't find the XLib.h file though. The file is located in /opt/X11/include/X11/ but idk how to tell Xcode that... Update: If I replace the path included in CImg with the absolute path of the Xlib.h file it works. I feel like I shouldn't have to do that though since others haven't had to rewrite the CImg code.

Comment: The `header search path` should be set to `/opt/X11/include` because inside `CImg.h` it does `#include <X11/XLib.h` which gets tacked onto the end of your search path.

Comment: What does it mean when the value <Multiple Values> is next to the header search paths? I only typed in /opt/X11/include but its displaying multiple values. Would that have an affect?

Comment: Just read your update. I get 20 more errors within the cwchar file (No member named "x" in the global namespace) after adding the new header and library paths. Is there something else I need to install?

Comment: Just a guess, but have you tried putting all those headers under "User Header Search Paths"?

Comment: Yep. That doesn't help.

Comment: Could you maybe try creating a small, fresh, brand-new Xcode project, just with the suggested settings I gave you and the code I gave you? I fear you have maybe tried lots of different things in desperation and left something set to a non-default value...

Comment: I made a new project with the given settings and I got the same errors. I think the problem might be something outside of Xcode. I'm going to reinstall XQuartz and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: If you have changed `CImg.h` grab a new copy of that too - it should not need changing at all.