# CImg.h can't run in Xcode environment

Tags: c++, cimg

*****Code*****

```
#include "CImg.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace cimg_library;

int main() {

    CImg<unsigned char> image("lena.png");

    image.display();

    return 0;

}
```

*****ERROR*****
Build successful but stuck somewhere:
OUTPUT:

[CImg] *** CImgIOException *** [instance(0,0,0,0,0x0,non-shared)] CImg::load(): Failed to open file 'lena.png'.
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cimg_library::CImgIOException: [instance(0,0,0,0,0x0,non-shared)] CImg::load(): Failed to open file 'lena.png'.

Comment: This is a problem in linking, the linker didn't find those functions. You can try check you added the frameworks/libraries to your project

Comment: It seems the CImg library uses [the X window system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) which you don't link with.

Comment: After add the framework libX11.6.dylib . There is only 1 ERROR left.

Comment: ERROR:  library not found for -lX11.6

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `CImg` on macOS, you need to do a couple of things.

### Step 1 - PNG support

If you want **CImg** to be able to open PNG files, you must first install `libpng` and `libz`, which you can do with **homebrew** as follows:

```
brew install libpng
```

Then you must tell **CImg** that you want it to include support for PNG files, which you do by declaring a define **before** including `CImg.h`

```
#define cimg_use_png 1
#include "CImg.h"
```

Then you must tell **Xcode** where the library is. That is easiest via `pkgconfig`, so install that with:

```
brew install pkg-config
```

Now you can get the path to the header files (#includes) with:

```
pkg-config --cflags /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libpng.pc
```

**Output**

```
-I/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.34/include/libpng16
```

That tells you what to put in **Xcode** for the paths to the header files. Then you need to find the Linker settings with:

```
pkg-config --libs /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libpng.pc
```

**Output**

```
-L/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.34/lib -lpng16 -lz
```

So you must put that into **Xcode** as the path for linked libraries and the names for libraries to link to.

### Step 2 - X11 suport

Once you have done that, and only if you want to display images on the screen, you need to set up **XQuartz** because **macOS** doesn't ship with an X11 server any more.

So, go [to this website](https://www.xquartz.org) and download and install **XQuartz**. You will then need to tell **Xcode** where the headers (#includes) for XQuartz are, which is:

```
/opt/X11/include
```

and also how to link with it:

```
-L /opt/X11/lib -lX11
```

There are some helpful screenshots of the places in **Xcode** you need to alter on my answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48399034/2836621).