# C++ Xcode 9 - failed to call function display() from Cimg

Tags: c++, macos, xcode9, cimg

I'm writing c++ program using **Cimg** in Xcode 9.0 MacOS 10.14
**Following is my code**

```
#include "CImg.h"
using namespace cimg_library;
int main(){
    CImg<unsigned char> img("1.bmp");
    auto w = img._width;
    auto h = img._height;
    printf("%d %d",w,h);
    img.display();
    return 0;
    
}
```

---

> The **width** and **height** of the pic is printed right
>
> But error occurs when it execute to `img.display()`

---

```
[CImg] *** CImgDisplayException *** CImgDisplay::screen_width(): 
Failed to open X11 display.
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type 
cimg_library::CImgDisplayException: CImgDisplay::screen_width(): 
Failed to open X11 display.
Program ended with exit code: 9
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `CImgDisplay disp(image, "Test");` instead of `img.display()`?

Comment: @HugoTeixeira tried, the message is `[CImg] *** CImgDisplayException *** [instance(0,0,0,[untitled])] CImgDisplay::assign(): Failed to open X11 display.
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cimg_library::CImgDisplayException: [instance(0,0,0,[untitled])] CImgDisplay::assign(): Failed to open X11 display.`

Answer (score 1):

**macOS** no longer ships with an X11 server, so if you want to use **CImg**'s `display()` function, you need to install **XQuartz**.

You also need to define `cimg_display` before #including `cimg.h`.

See also [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48399034/2836621).

Make sure you can run `xclock` before even trying to display from **CImg**.